# Set the file name and open blob pdf type in new tab

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to open the blob byte streams in the new tab of the browser. It is works, but I am not sure how to set the file name so that each of the documents will have the unique name when downloaded. Now, the document was defaulted to 'document.pdf' when saved.

```
var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
            if (blob) {
                var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.open(fileURL);
            }
```

Comment: Sadly it is not possibe
A way to achieve this effect with an IFRAME is shown in [How to prevent blob + guid in browser title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451958/how-to-prevent-blob-guid-in-browser-title)

Comment: Try with File interface. window.URL.createObjectURL(new File([blob], 'filename.pdf', {type:"application/pdf"}));

Answer (score -9):

Give it a filename with the [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) call:

```js
window.open(fileURL, "your filename.extension");
```

If you are using IE, use [`navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh772332(v=vs.85).aspx) instead:

```js
navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(fileURL, "your filename.extension");
```

Comment: In IE the file could not be open new tab,just will be download

Comment: no. it ignore "your filename.extension"