# how to save file with name in a download function with javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, download

I have a function in my web app that allows me to download a present image. What I would also like it to do is give me the opportunity to save this file under the name upon download.

My function is this:

```js
 function saveFile(){
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); 
      console.log(dataURL);
      window.location.href = dataURL; 
    }
```

And how can I do to name this file?
Thank u all!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File download - How can I control the filename AND respect the users preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828475/file-download-how-can-i-control-the-filename-and-respect-the-users-preferences)

Answer (score -1):

First create `anchor tag` and add `href` and `download` attribute to provide the uri and fileName respectively.

```
function saveFile(){
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); 
      console.log(dataURL);
      const anchorLink = document.createElement('a');
      document.body.appendChild(anchorLink)
      anchorLink.href = dataURL;
      anchorLink.download = "file_name.png"; 
      anchorLink.click();
      document.body.removeChild(anchorLink)
}
```

Comment: The `location` object isn't an anchor element. It doesn't have a `download` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location