# Based on mime type, either open PDF in popup or download word document

Tags: html

I have a function that opens a pdf in a dialog box. It looks something like this:

```js
async function openPDFDialog (src)
{
    // ...
    modalDlg.querySelector('embed').src = src;
    // ...
}
```

If I have a url, eg. `/orderFile/0/0`.

Based on the mime type I want it to perform a different action:

- `application/pdf` -> open in dialog box
- `application/msword` -> download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need to `fetch` the file and get the mime type.

- The mime type you included was `application/msword` however this is for `.doc` files not `.docx`. The correct mime type for `.docx` is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`.

To avoid requesting the url twice, you can save the response as a `Blob`.

From there, based on the mime type, you use the url from the Blob to do the required action.

```js
let response = await fetch(src);
let mimeType = response.headers.get("Content-Type");
let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(await response.blob());
if (mimeType === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
{
    let a = Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {
        href: blobURL,
        download: "filename.docx"
    });
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();    
    a.remove();
}
else if (mimeType === 'application/pdf')
{
    await openPDFDialog(blobURL);
}
```

Comment: The only problem is the file name shown will just be a guid. You can see a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548182/can-i-set-the-filename-of-a-pdf-object-displayed-in-chrome